# Windows Docker Toolbox won't start

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

Attempting to start up Docker Toolbox 1.12.0 on Windows 10 and getting the following error

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\abc\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\abc\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe createvm --basefolder C:\Users\abc\.docker\machine\machines\default --name default --register failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG (0x80040155) - Interface not registered (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "CreateMachine(bstrSettingsFile.raw(), bstrName.raw(), ComSafeArrayAsInParam(groups), bstrOsTypeId.raw(), createFlags.raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 272 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp

Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking if machine default exists´... Press any key to continue...
```

Has anyone encountered this error before?

Comment: This looks like virtualboxes network subsystem is having troubles. Try restarting the vbox services.  Also, have you tried Docker for Windows? They moved away from using VirtualBox to provide an easier to use and manage environment.

Comment: @Matt I am still not sure how hyper-v is better than VirtualBox... Can I create multiple machines (ie different VM) with Hyper-V the same way I could with VB?

Comment: @VonC I'm not sure that it's *better* either. xhyve is even worse for that as there is no admin interface. "Easier to use and manage" isn't the feature set for everyone but I think it does make life easier for first time users and for VirtualBoxy things like this.

Comment: @Matt Right... as an old timer, I'll stick with my VB ;)

Comment: @VonC Yep! One good thing is the docker image has moved to Alpine from TinyCore. I'm hoping that change is ported over to `docker-machine`/`boot2docker`.

Comment: @Matt Me too, but... that does not seem to be the case just yet: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/4dd80d729c477a85c0549be7fe351eaa50930797/Dockerfile#L113

Comment: One day... I didn't realise enabling hyper-v stopped you from using vbox. At least the mac can run both types. I left this q in case anyone feels like filling in the detail: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899980/1318694

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing VirtualBox and then restarting my machine fixed the problem. Hopefully this fixes yours too.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by reinstalling VirtualBox, and choosing `repair` mode.

`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\installers\virtualbox` -> **virtualbox.exe**.

After finishing the process, restart you machine and smile!