# What features do Docker for Mac/Windows provide over Docker Toolbox on my development box?

Tags: docker

Docker have recently released [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) and [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) for running Linux containers on their respective environments.

What features have been added or changed compared to the original Docker Toolbox and `docker-machine` method of running Docker containers?

Are their any clear advantages or disadvantages to using the new Docker tools for my development?

Answer (score 1):

The main profit is that docker-machine isn't mandatory anymore. Containers are run naturally in system but not in Virtual Box as before.